# How do I use my function components props to set my state with usestate()?

Tags: reactjs

So i have been trying to use the usestate() hook in my functional component and i've been trying to use the information passed down as a prop in a form input field. I can directly use the prop just fine. But when i try to use it in my Usestate() it just shows up as undefined.

like this:

```
const [state, setstate] = useState({
    title: prop1.title,
});
```

And this is what a component it would be inside would look like

```
function Functionname({ prop1}) {}
```

This is the constructor of the parent

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        prop1: {},

    }
```

The fetch method

```
fetch(`api/SampleData/GetProp1/${this.props.match.params.prop1Id}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ prop1: data});

            });
```

The the parent return

```
 return (
        <div>

            <Prop1component prop1={this.state.prop1} />
        </div>


    );
```

Sorry if i'm missing some inforation and thanks in advance

edit: added some more information.

edit 2: Max pointed out that i should change {prop1.title} to prop1.title this works if i just define the state in the constructor, but not when i have to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understarded well, but if this is the functional declaration:

```
function Functionname({ prop1}) {}
```

then the use state I think could be:

```
const [state, setstate] = useState({
    title: prop1.title,
});
```

Comment: Hi Max Thanks for helping me. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. It still shows the state title as undefined

Comment: Can you tell me what is the props value you passing?

Comment: It is a object that is fetched from a database. It just contains some strings. I can access them just fine outside of the usestate().

Comment: If your props for example is **{prop1:{title:'test', ...}, ...}** and define state as before, then the state should be **{title:'test'}** and you can access with **state.title**

Comment: I dont understand why, but mine stays undefined.